# javascript replace not workings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem with replace not working.

```
alert($('input#membership_edc').next("label").html().replace(/£/g, ""));
```

The value of the label after the input would be £24.00, but I want to do a math on that value then put it back with the new value. It's not removing the pound sign.

What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: you can use replace("£", "")

Comment: *"It's not removing the pound sign."* Not removing it *where*? It won't be shown in the `alert`, you're definitely removing it from the string you pass to `alert` ([proof](http://jsbin.com/etizuy)). That doesn't change anything *else*.

Comment: What are you trying to do, why are you removing the `£` in the first place?

Comment: as I've said here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10176894/643580, the code is working. you must have a markup or a script error elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read/modify/write use the *function parameter* version of `.html()`:

```
$('input#membership_edc').next("label").html(function(index, old) {
    var n = parseFloat(old.replace('£', '');
    return n + 10;
});
```

would replace '£24.00' with '34'.

Comment: I don't think the OP want's the replace the HTML (at least not the pound sign)... he just wants to extract the numeric value to perform calculations. *edit:* as it seems he want to put the changed value back, this could still be useful.

Comment: I think you mean `var n = parseFloat(old);` or simply `var n = +old.replace('£', '');`. Strings don't have a `parseFloat` method.

Comment: @FelixKling duh, yes... (blush)

Comment: I think I've found the error. If I view the pound sign in the source, it's not a pound sign, it's a "miss-matched character set" question mark. I can't replace the string I'm finding with &pound; then search for that, though. :( I get NaN when I run that code above.

Comment: @i-CONICA Try using '\xa3` instead of the £ symbol

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the value returned from the replace. Try below,

```
var $label = $('input#membership_edc').next("label");
$label.html($label.html().replace(/£/g, ""));
```

Comment: I don't think the OP want's the replace the HTML... he just wants to extract the numeric value to perform calculations.

Comment: Correct Felix, I just want the numeric value so that I can perform a mathematical operation on it, then put it back modified.

Comment: @i-CONICA I see, Check the fiddle posted by http://stackoverflow.com/a/10176894/297641 seems to work. Check for any script error.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong. It is working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m7DyJ/).
Are you sure your markup is fine?

Answer (score 0):

The string replace function *returns* a new string. Strings themselves are immutable in javascript, I think. As Vega has it:

```
// avoid looking this up twice
var label = alert($('input#membership_edc').next("label"); 
// replace and assign
label.html(label.html().replace(/£/g, ""));
```

Edit:

To get the numerical value from the string:

```
var amount = alert($('input#membership_edc').next("label").html().match(/£\s*([-0-9.]+)/)[1];
```

This matches the numbers etc after the £ (ignoring whitespace), and uses index 1 from the array, containing the contents of the first group match (in the brackets).

```
" £1.45".match(/£\s*([-0-9.]+)/)[1]; // returns "1.45"
```

Beware that it is still a string, so you might want to do parseFloat on it.

Comment: Seems like that is not what OP wants.. see the comments in my answer.